# DotNetNuke 7 Module Development Template using VS2008 DotNetNuke.dll reference error

Tags: c#, templates, module, dotnetnuke

Installed DNN 7.0.4 and tried both DotNetNuke6 C# Module Development Template and DotNetNuke Project Templates VSIX v2.4 which uses VS2012. Creates and opens the template module fine in VS2008. But I get a warning icon on the DotNetNuke.dll in References. When compiling my module, I get "DotNetNuke namespace does not exist" error.

FYI - when I open the DNN website project, I do not see this warning icon on the DotNetNuke.dll so I know the bin folder's DotNetNuke.dll is a good version. Or am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by removing the DNN reference and try adding it again to the websites/bin/dotnetnuke.dll file.

Comment: Chris, Thanks. 

I've removed and re-added a few times and get the same result using path c:/websites/dnndev/bin/dotnetnuke.dll.

Also, I compiled using VS2008 with .NET 3.5 (NOT .NET 4.0). Would that make a difference? I wonder if the dotnetnuke.dll that came with DNN 7.0.4 is compiled using VS2012 with .NET 4.0 or higher? Therefore, that's why VS2008 is telling me to re-build. 

Do I need to use VS2010 Visual Studio Express or higher to recognize the dotnetnuke.dll that came with DNN 7.0.4? Or is there a compatible version of dotnetnuke.dll compiled wih VS2008 .NET 3.5 available somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I did miss the fact that you were trying to do this with DNN 7. It does require 4.0. I'm not sure VS2008 will do 4.0, but 2010 and 2012 will.

Comment: Chris - That was it!!! Downloaded VS2012 Express and was able to compile using .NET 4.0 Framework and the dotnetnuke.dll had no errors. Thank you for your response!!

Comment: I am following along on this guide: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155064/module-development-for-non-developers-skinners-dnn-beginners--blog-series-intro and it works fine for dnn 7.04.02. But as soon as I tried it on 8.0.0 it would never compile. So after reading the above comment, I decided to try and switch the Target Framework from 4.0 to 4.5 and bam it started to compile again!